# Scaling/Displaying the Y axis Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm very new to Python/data sets.  I am not sure of the terminology to use when describing my question.  As a result it's been difficult searching for answers.  I have plotted a data set that ranges 0 - 20,000,000,000,000 for the y axis. Here is what I have:

[image]

However, for my assignment it should look like so:

[image]

I have tried ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis='y') which gives me:

[image]

This give me the numbers with no scientific notation and too many zeros!  I'm not sure which methods I should be using to scale(?) the numbers.  I've thought about operating on my raw data values but that doesn't seem right.  I have looked at the documentation for matplotlib.pyplot.yscale but unless I'm missing something it doesn't seem to be what I need.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Does the assignment allow you to scale your raw dataset before plotting to matplotlib? You could use numpy to convert your y-axis data to a numpy array and then divide by 1E9 which would appropriately scale all elements of the dependent variable (and then specify the scaling in the y-axis label)

Comment: I have three lists each containing 57 items/values.  I plot each one separately - plt.plot(x axis,dataset_1), plt.plot(x axis,dataset_2) etc.  I ended up just iterating through each list and dividing the values by 10**9.  How would this work with numpy?  Can you give me more detail?  Thanks.

Comment: Of course! Check out my example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scale your data using a [numpy.array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) and then specify the scaling in the y-axis:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

#scale the data appropriately with numpy.array
dataset_1 = np.array(dataset_1)
scaled_dataset_1 = dataset_1/(10**9)

#plot with scaling specified in label
plt.plot(x_axis, scaled_dataset_1)
plt.ylabel('Dataset 1 (10^9)')
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the Y-axis to exponential, you can use the following settings Please refer to this [page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/ticks_and_spines/scalarformatter.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

x = np.arange(0, 200000000, 1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))

ax.plot(x * 1000000, x * 100000)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter(useMathText=True))
ax.ticklabel_format(style="sci",  axis="y", scilimits=(0,0))

plt.show()
```

[image]